# nlminb with bounds: is it L-BFGS-B under the hood?

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization

Title says it all. Any insight would be much appreciated.

background: 
I understand that Douglas Bates imported a "PORT routine" to R (original implementation by David Gay of Bell Labs). But I can't find the relevant documentation of the mathematics.